# Android volley Socket is closed

Tags: android, proxy, fiddler, android-volley, socketexception

I Started using volley library for web service requests and it works just fine. When I want to set a proxy to see the requests through Fiddler I can't see any. The error I'm getting is:  com.android.volley.NoConnectionError: java.net.SocketException: Socket is closed

Can someone explain why this happens and how to make it work?

Comment: It will help to share your code. Are you using HTTPS or HTTP?

Comment: I'm using HTTPS. Could it be that volley prevents a "Man in the middle attack" and closes the socket when proxy is set? If this is true can some debugging flag be set to let my requests pass?

Comment: Did you configure Android to trust the Fiddler root certificate?

Comment: Yes I did. I tested with http requests and it works but with https it doesn't. Any other ideas?

Comment: That strongly suggests that the certificate isn't trusted by Android. What specifically did you do on the Android device? Are you seeing this for ALL HTTPS Urls, or just a specific one?

Comment: My app has usual HttpRequests too. They work fine even if I set up my device for fiddler. Only the volley https requests fail. It's not only for a specific URL

Comment: How are you proxying to fiddler? ProxyDroid? System setting proxy?

Comment: System setting proxy.

Comment: This is an old thread, but I just came across the same problem. What I have experienced was that Volley somehow bypasses Fiddler sometimes. Not quite sure what is going on yet, still investigating, but as it seems to me Volley disregards the proxy setting on the system.